# Facebook App not displaying

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-apps

I've created a few apps/pages however i recently created a new one and it wont display at all in Facebook (fine on mobile?). Its a simple page with html, Nothing special.

I'm using Google App engine as its not a paying job so the free https:// is helpful. I've used app engine before and it works fine with FB.

I created ate app on March 3rd and have read multiple articles saying FB changes a few things(again!).

I'm noticing in Firebug that there  is a post made from FB to my app which fails with a 405 method.

Does anyone know a simple way to get around this in App engine.

The app page is https://apps.facebook.com/abacas-facebook/

the app itself is https://abacasfacebook.appspot.com/

ps the login button etc are just things i was trying out. The page is just text

Here the app code(nothing complicate at all)

MAIN.PY

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template 


class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.out.write(template.render('index.html', {}))
        def post(self):
    self.response.out.write(template.render('index.html', {}))

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                         debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks
Si

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your redirect URLS' correctly setup?

https://developers.facebook.com/apps
Is your "website" site URL pointing to your web domain?

Also are you properly including the facebook javascript sdk's? I don't see where you're including the facebook social login button if you are.

Comment: Hi David, 

yes my "website" is https://abacasfacebook.appspot.com/ and the domain is appspot both which worked on previous apps(using appspot domain).

I'm including the JS SDK if you view source on the page.  I have a log in button at the bottom of the page

S